# Numpy transpose functions speed and use cases

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

So why is the NumPy transpose `.T` faster than `np.transpose()`?

```
b = np.arange(10)

#Transpose .T
t=b.reshape(2,5).T

#Transpose function
t = np.transpose(b.reshape(2,5))

#Transpose function without wrapper
t = b.reshape(2,5).transpose()
```

I did a `timeit` of both in Jupyter:

```
%timeit -n 1000 b.reshape(2,5).T

1000 loops, best of 3: 391 ns per loop

%timeit -n 1000 np.transpose(b.reshape(2,5))

1000 loops, best of 3: 600 ns per loop

%timeit -n 1000 b.reshape(2,5).transpose()

1000 loops, best of 3: 422 ns per loop
```

and to check scaleablility I did a larger matrix:

```
b = np.arange( 100000000)

%timeit -n 1000 b.reshape(10000,10000).T

1000 loops, best of 3: 390 ns per loop

%timeit -n 1000 np.transpose(b.reshape(10000,10000))

1000 loops, best of 3: 611 ns per loop

%timeit -n 1000 b.reshape(10000,10000).transpose()

1000 loops, best of 3: 435 ns per loop
```

In both cases the `.T` method about 2x faster than the wrapper and a bit faster than using `.transpose()` why is this?  Is there a use case where `np.transpose` would be better?

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about the speed of `transpose`.  It's a trivial action, just changing shape and strides.  The differences you see just reflect the calling structure.  They don't vary with the size of the array.

Comment: @hpaulj why not? when you are working with large datasets every bit of time adds up.

Comment: @hpaulj is referring to the fact that transposing just involves manipulating the arrays describing the *layout* of the data, not the data itself. This operation scales with number of dimensions, which is much smaller than the sizes of those dimensions.

Comment: `np.transpose` is also used in `argwhere`, `return transpose(nonzero(a))`.  Here `transpose` first turns the tuple of arrays into a 2d array.  A tuple doesn't have a transpose method.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason might be that `np.transpose(a)` just calls `a.transpose()` internally, while `a.transpose()` is more direct.  In the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L529-L575) you have:

```
def transpose(a, axes=None):
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
```

Where `_wrapfunc` in turn [is just](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L50):

```
def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
```

This maps to `getattr(a, 'transpose')` in this case.  `_wrapfunc` is used by many of the module-level functions to access methods, usually of the `ndarray` class or whatever is the class of the first arg.

(Note: `.T` is the same as `.transpose()`, except that the array is returned if it has <2 dimensions.)

Comment: @Brad_Solomon so I tried using .transpose() but .T was still faster I will update my post

Comment: I think `ndarray.transpose()` might be marginally faster because it takes an `axes` parameter whereas `.T` does not.  But it certainly shouldn't be a factor of 2x.

Comment: @Brad_Solomon I guess numpy has to check the axes parameter which creates more overhead in `.transpose()` but not in `.T`  Thanks