# Difference between numpy routines and ndarray methods?

Tags: python, numpy

When using `numpy`, often times one can choose between calling a function from the `numpy` API, and calling the function from the `ndarray`, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array_ = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> np.any(array_)
True
>>> array_.any()
True
```

Functionally these seem identical to me;
Are they?
Are they programmatically different? (e.g. performance/memory wise)

I tried finding the answer in the `numpy` reference manual about [ndarrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and [routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.html), but as far as I can tell no explanation is given.

Comment: Well if you perform a `some_array.foo`, then in case `foo` is not attached to the `some_array`, it will fallback to `numpy.foo(array(some_array))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One note on terminology first so the rest of this example is clear--`np.any(arr)` is a function; `arr.any()` is technically an instance method.

---

Generally, the top-level `np.<function>(arr)` functions are wrappers around the methods for `arr`.

Here's the source for `np.any()`, NumPy version 1.14.5, from `numpy.core.fromnumeric`:

```
def any(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue):
    arr = asanyarray(a)
    kwargs = {}
    if keepdims is not np._NoValue:
        kwargs['keepdims'] = keepdims
    return arr.any(axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
```

Other versions of NumPy (such as the [one currently on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7598437d7547844e860a7dc4626294f6e4107aad/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2030)) may use a "[wrapper factory function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7598437d7547844e860a7dc4626294f6e4107aad/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L36)" that does virtually the same thing.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509746/7954504) Q/A for a similar example with `np.transpose()`.  Generally what it boils down to is `np.<function>(arr)` becomes some form of `getattr(arr, <function>)`, at least for the stuff in [`fromnumeric.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py).

---

In terms of a comparison--you're talking about an incremental amount of additional overhead when using the top-level function, but that comes with some added flexibility: for instance, there's a call to `np.asanyarray(a)`, which means you could pass a Python list as `a` to the function.  On my computer, the call to `np.asanyarray(arr)` takes 1/8 the time of `arr.any()`, so to inject a bit of opinion into the answer, choosing between the two is probably not the first place to look in terms of performance optimization.